# How to model queries in Power BI for daily append of new data instead of overwriting

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to build a simple report in Power BI based upon data published on a website. 
Here is what I want to achieve

1. This website publishes data for COVID cases in the country.
2. The number are just the current numbers, without any time-series.
3. I want to fetch these numbers from this website daily and build a report on
   top of it (with time series kind of analysis).
4. So I fetch these numbers (Get Data > Web > URL) and get this into a query I then add
   a custom column with a timestmap (M's DateTime.LocalNow() function)
   and get this data with the required timestamp.
5. Now I want to refresh this query daily, so that I get daily results in this query. 
   **6. As expected, PBI simply overwrites the existing rows with new data,
   with the latest timestamp (my custom column).**

I tried few things like:-

1. Creating a new query and appending data to it, it doesn't seem to work, existing data gets over-written (maybe the way I have created the new query).
2. Explored incremental refresh functionality, it doesn't seem to fit my use case.
3. Tried looking at other similar posts, none seem to help me resolve this.

Questions:-

1. Is there a simple workaround to circumvent this (point#7) and have PBI append new data instead of overwriting existing data.
2. Am i correct on point#2 above (incremental refresh)?

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simple workaround is to build an ETL process to fetch data daily, save the data somewhere (a database would be a good choice), and build the report to read the data from this data source instead.

Comment: Incremental refresh only works on the power bi service. You have to publish the report with a Pro account or Premium.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Won't an ETL process for this simple requirement be an overkill (just need to fetch a table from a webpage daily and add it to my PBI model). I just feel there should be some workaround/tweak to get this kind of a setup directly working in PBI

Comment: @mxix I do have a Pro subscription. However I think this feature is not applicable here. Incremental refresh is for larger dataset (DWH) where we need to do delta updates (new data only). In my use case, every time I do refresh I need to consider all data as new data and put a timestamp on it in PowerQuery. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple workaround within Power BI.

Power BI is not designed to be used as a database where you store historical data. It's designed to connect to data and create reports from that, so you'll need to store the daily data somewhere external.

There are tons of ways to store the data. E.g., you could save them as CSVs in a folder that Power BI loads from or you could write them to a database table and connect to that.

---

**Edit**: That said, there is a non-simple workaround if this is something you really must do.

Though not recommended, you can [use incremental refresh](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/04/13/keep-the-existing-data-in-your-power-bi-dataset-and-add-new-data-to-it-using-incremental-refresh/) to trick Power BI into doing what you want.

Comment: Agree with you in principal, however PBI does provide Power Query which does provide some basic data manipulation. To think of it, IMO my use case just captures current data from a website and needs to append it to data already existing in PBI model. To me this doesn't seem like historical data concept, please correct me if I'm wrong. I just feel there should be some workaround/tweak to get this kind of a setup working in PBI.

Comment: Yes, Power Query does data manipulation. You are wanting it to do data storage as well. To append new data to existing data, you have to store that existing data somewhere.

Comment: PBI does provide storage (the import mode atleat). One would think that PBI as a tool may provide a workaround or a quick hack to have it append data rather than replace it as part of a refresh.

Comment: It only stores the result of the query when importing, not every previous result you've ever loaded too. If you want to keep those previous results, then you need to save them somewhere.

Comment: Makes sense. How about one creates a model with two queries. One query (Q1) to get/refresh daily data and then another query (Q2) which gets its data from Q1 as an append operation (and its refresh disabled). Just a wild thought, not sure if its possible.

Comment: OK, but then the next day you have to have Q1 already appended to Q2 and saved so you can get new data to append and not lose the previous day's data. Basically, you'll have to set up a new query every day.

Comment: I haven't had much experience appending queries so can't exactly grasp what you mentioned, but can relate to the same since I tried doing the same (I could see my append query's data was also getting overwritten). I think the ETL approach (having an intermediate data source to stage and transform data) would probably make more sense in this case or I can try looking for a new data source with time series done there itself. Thanks.