# How can i preserve old data in powerbi?

Tags: api, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using web api to import data into powerbi. After every refresh, old data is replaced by new data of web api so my question is how can I store that old data in power bi ?

Comment: See related discussion and links here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948771/how-to-model-queries-in-power-bi-for-daily-append-of-new-data-instead-of-overwri

Answer (score 0):

Power BI will not store data, unless you have a query source that will support incremental refresh.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-incremental-refresh

It would be best to use a tool like Azure Function, Azure Logic Apps or Power Automate to get the data and save it as file to a folder then import the data from the folder. Other option would be to move the data to a database table to preserve the history.